# Need code that uses XmlReader only for gathering error messages from WCF Trace files

Tags: .net, wcf, xmlreader

I am using the following method to gather error messages from WCF Trace files. The problem with this code is the `XPathDocument` use. If there are any errors in the file, the document will not load.

Does anyone have code, samples, or examples that duplicates the method, but uses only a `XmlReader`. I am trying to avoid the complete failure and skip over any "E2ETraceEvent" elements that are not well-formed.

For instance, one exception I am trying to avoid is "Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 1, position 15716165."

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates a list of error messages from the specified trace file.
/// </summary>
public static List<string> GatherErrorMessages(string path, string entryHeader, string entryFooter)
{
    List<string> oResult = new List<string>();

    XmlReaderSettings oSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    oSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

    using (FileStream oStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        XPathDocument oDocument = new XPathDocument(XmlReader.Create(oStream, oSettings));
        XPathNavigator oNavigator = oDocument.CreateNavigator();

        XmlNamespaceManager oManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(oNavigator.NameTable);
        oManager.AddNamespace("e", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent");
        oManager.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system");

        XPathNodeIterator oEvents = oNavigator.Select("/e:E2ETraceEvent", oManager);

        while (oEvents.MoveNext())
        {
            XPathNavigator oErrorNode = oEvents.Current.SelectSingleNode("s:System/s:SubType[@Name=\"Error\"]", oManager);

            if (oErrorNode != null)
            {
                XPathNavigator oErrorMessageNode = oEvents.Current.SelectSingleNode("e:ApplicationData/text()", oManager);

                oResult.Add(entryHeader + oErrorMessageNode.Value + entryFooter);
            }
        }
    }

    return oResult;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this "by hand" rather than using [Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)?

Comment: I need to insert the error messages into a message from the client.

Comment: Have you considered using [IDispatchMessageInspector Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) and [IClientMessageInspector Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector)?  If you are able to catch the error, it seems it would be easier to use these interfaces to modify the message to include the error than to try and manually parse the trace logs.

Comment: I just added a `XmlWriterTraceListener` to `Trace` to easily log information is a large project I inherited. I want to parse out the errors, but due to a flaky application, I get partial elements written because `Trace` is not flushed properly. (`Trace.AutoFlush` does not completely eliminate the partial elements.)